# Trying to Add Sub Row Group inside Parent but flush left in the nested cell

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to create nested groups but I want the sub row group to show directly underneath the parent, flush to the left like the parent.

So in this case You'd have:

```
Market
SubMarket
```

so results for example would be:

```
California <<< market
SanJose
Pleasanton
Walnut Creek

Illinois <<< market
Chicago Suburbs
Chicago
```

... and so on

I cannot figure out why the heck I can't get a child row group to show directly under a

Can anyone help me on this?  I'm truly frustrated with SSRS.  No idea why it doesn't just add the grouping right on the cell I had clicked.  Instead it creates new columns!  Yea by design but why?  and how to get around this.  What I am trying to do seems so simple...yet so hard in SSRS.

**Here's an example of what I tried to do:**

- **Creating a Parent Row Group Within a Parent**: If you click a cell within a parent group (in this case Market) and then add another parent group on that cell it'll add a new column in your SSRS report to the RIGHT of the parent that you are in:

[image]

- **Creating a Child Row Group Within a Parent**: If you are in a Parent Group and click on a cell and add a child row group, it'll add the row to the right of the parent

[image]

**What I want this to do is this**, and I can't get SSRS to put that submarket here:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, what you want is certainly possible, and it's certainly a pain to get it to work. Here's a small example with some mock data that should be more or less analogous to your situation.

The dataset:

```
Market    SubMarket
------    ---------
A         1
A         2
A         3
B         4
B         5
B         6
B         7
```

Here are the steps I've taken to create the table:

1. Drag/drop a new, fresh table to the designer.
2. Drag/drop the `SubMarket` field to the first column.
3. Right-click the detail row and add a new parent group.

   [image: Add parent group]
4. Group on `Market` and choose to add a group header row.

   [image: New group settings]

   As you've already noted, SSRS "helps" and adds an extra column.
5. Right-click the extra (first) column and delete it.
6. Select the cell in the header row for the group and enter "[Market]", or pick it from the quick-list.

   [image: Add field to header row]
7. Finish up by filling in the other fields/columns/cells. For the header row drag/drop won't work, you'll have to pick the fields for that row yourself (or type 'em).

   This is the resulting table in preview (with some emphasis on the header row):

   [image: Sample output]

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks I actually did it another way (figured it out finally) but this is cool to know of one more way to do this.

Comment: this article helped me so I used the concepts in here but I had to do several things different than this guy for mine for several reasons.  So pretty crazy what you have to do to get this stuff how you want.  Mine had a bit different route than this guy's but his ideas gave me a good thought about how to go about it.  http://www.bidn.com/blogs/kylewalker/ssis/657/how-to-create-a-single-column-multiple-group-grouping-in-ssrs