# Add Sub Row Group inside Parent Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, reportbuilder

I've already made this table below (I've made `Groups column` as `parent group` and the `Status Column` as `Child group`), what I need to add now, is to put the `Status` (column2) inside the `Group` (Column1):

[image]

It want it to look like this !

[image]

Can somebody please help me reach this display !

Comment: The following question seems very similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954323/trying-to-add-sub-row-group-inside-parent-but-flush-left-in-the-nested-cell.
Check it out, you might need to add footer instead of header though, your child grouping seems below of the regular status fields..

Comment: I have already tried this ansewer it's not what I wanted :(

Answer (score 0):

On the Row Groups panel, right click on the Child Group and select 'Add Total'