# Adding Grouping in Tablix SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

So I have a query that puts out the following

```
ID          Name          Birthday
----        -------       ------------
1           John          9/22/1982
1           Sandra        2/1/1981
2           Steven        3/2/1984
2           Stephanie     5/14/1983
3           Kevin         8/15/1983
3           Kelly         9/12/1985
```

What i want to do is group by id:

```
 + 1
     John      9/22/1982   
     Sandra    2/1/1981
 + 2 
     Steven    3/2/1984
     Stephanie 5/14/1983
 - 3
```

Obvisouly the +/- represent the toggle for the grouping. My current issue is that I'm only getting 1 record for every group. Here are my current settings

- ID row is the parent row
- Name and Birthday are the child row.
- Dataset results show the way I had above
- I followed these steps throughout from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954323/trying-to-add-sub-row-group-inside-parent-but-flush-left-in-the-nested-cell)

Not really sure what to do or where I should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you only have a single row inside your group, it indicates that you aren't grouping on the field ID.

I followed these steps to create the table you described:

1. Create the dataset as you described (top 4 rows)
2. Right-click on report and insert table
3. Right click on the Row Groups "(Details)" area and add a parent group:
   [image]
4. In the properties for "(Details)", set the visibility toggle information:[image]
5. Setup the columns in the table accordingly:[image]

If you want to try to fix the table that you have started creating, look at the group properties for the "ID" row group (if created) and ensure that it's grouping on the field ID.  If it doesn't exist, create the parent group to the details as described above.

Comment: Thank you! I had a difficult time getting this done with a Tablix, but your steps were awesome. Simple and easy.